# Views not being copied when publish the project in netcore 2.0 visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

I have createa a ASP.NET Core 2.0 project in VS 2017. When I publish my project the `Views` folder are not there but the `wwwroot` folder is.

This I can setup in my .csproj file with the following:

```
<ItemGroup>                                                                            
   <Content Update="appsettings.json;web.config" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest"/>
   <Content Update="Views\**\*" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
   <Content Update="wwwroot\**\*" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

but didn't work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

ASP.NET Core MVC has a [precompilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?tabs=aspnetcore2x) feature, that could be added by referencing the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation` package. Feature enabling/disabling configured by `MvcRazorCompileOnPublish` property is .csproj.

And by default, the package is added in ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC applications:

> If you're targeting ASP.NET Core 2.0 or higher on netcoreapp2.0, a reference to the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation](https://github.com/aspnet/MvcPrecompilation) package is added by Microsoft.AspNetCore.All and you do not need to explicitly reference it.

and [precompilation is enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?tabs=aspnetcore2x):

> The ASP.NET Core 2.x project templates implicitly set `MvcRazorCompileOnPublish` to true by default, which means this node can be safely removed from the .csproj file:
>
> ```
> <PropertyGroup>
>     <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
>     <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
>   </PropertyGroup>
> ```

If you go to publish output folder, you will see dll like `<project_name>.PrecompiledViews.dll` which contains your views.

Comment: I used this solution in a ASP.NET project and it worked for me. I could see the .cshtml files in the build output. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

In .NET Core 3.1 or later, we need to add the following code in **.csproj**:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  <CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>true</CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>
```

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/sdk?view=aspnetcore-5.0):

> When `true`, copies `RazorGenerate` items (*.cshtml*) files to the publish directory. Typically, Razor files aren't required for a published app if they participate in compilation at build-time or publish-time. Defaults to `false`.

Answer (score 4):

It might be generating `<project_name>.Views.dll` by default. You need to set `MvcRazorCompileOnPublish`property `false` in your project `.csproj` file. By default it is `true`.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>    
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

On 3.1, I have tried all of the above with no .cshtml files appearing. Interesting, I do get .cs files copied across to publish folders. i.e. in my csproj, the first two work - the other does not

```
   <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Pages\AisLayout.cs">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Pages\Application.cs">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="Pages\ApplicationState.cshtml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Update="Pages\Cookies.cshtml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
```

If I manually copy the files, I am able to modify them with dynamic recompile occurring (as expected).  Note: The .cshtml has no code behind files (long story).

More suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone ended up here struggling with dotnet 6 or higher:

> The Razor compiler no longer produces a separate Views.dll file that contains the CSHTML views defined in an application.

[documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/6.0/razor-compiler-doesnt-produce-views-assembly)