# asp.net core 2.1.0 Publish customised identity UI views

Tags: web-deployment, areas, asp.net-core-2.1

Customised Identity UI razor pages not being deployed to server when publishing to IIS using Web Deploy.

Is there any specific configuration I need to add to use ?

According to Docs   is already included in in .csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I noticed that in the csproj file I had

```
<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
```

Which was needed in 2.0. I simply removed it in 2.1 and it worked.

Perhaps you can give that a try

Answer (score 0):

I have added these lines to my `.csproj` and fixed it. more info is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46688453/790896)

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
</PropertyGroup>
```